# What is the GCC Option to emulate Microsoft C compiler behavior?

Tags: c, visual-c++, gcc

I'm developing a C library for both Linux and Windows. As Microsofts' compiler appears to be a bit backwards in some regards, and I'm mostly coding on Ubuntu, I would like to make GCC behave in a similar way, so I can anticipate the compiler errors I would encounter with MSVC.

Google keeps quiet on my question. Could anyone point me to a source of information? Much obliged!

Comment: Why would GCC add an option to behave like MSVC?

Comment: @Nick: To support source using MS-specific constructs such as unnamed unions/struct members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use `-pedantic -ansi` - that makes gcc try to accept only completely standard C89 source.

`-fms-extensions` adds support for some VC-specific extensions.

Comment: +1 You learn something new every day - I'm not surprised however given the open nature of GCC and the ability for anyone to contribute.